# How to set different layout/template for static pages for not logged in users?

Tags: magento

I found a topic about [customizing magento to use page template when cart is empty](http://www.tonigrigoriu.com/magento/how-to-use-a-different-template-when-the-cart-is-empty/), but I need to customize template, when user is guest.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by user is a guest?
You mean non-logged in user? or checkout type = register / guest / login ?
if it's for non-logged in user then you can simply check with

```
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
   //if user is logged in
endif;
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do I need to write it? I need just to change template for static pages.